# Bash : Number of Days Between Today and Very Far Future Date

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the number of days between today's date and very far date in future (02/25/2362). The dates are formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +%m/%d/%Y)
purge_date="02/25/2362"

#echo "$now"
#echo "$purge_date"

date1_unix=`date -d $now +%s`
date2_unix=`date -d $purge_date +%s`

#echo "$date1_unix"
#echo "$date2_unix"

diff=`expr $date2_unix - $date1_unix`
diff_days=`expr $diff / 86400` # Number of seconds in a day are 86400
echo $diff_days
```

This approach works when the future date is near but for year 2362 as shown, I get an error:

```
date: invalid date `02/25/2362'
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
```

Comment: I doubt that there is still bash in 2362.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow you.

Comment: it could be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @ritesht93 : Thank you for sharing this. Do you know anyway where I can achieve the aforementioned goal.

Comment: Yes it is possible.. Can you use something else like python where numbers have no size limit .. I mean you would have to perform just the date difference calculation in python.. You can take inputs from bash

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  I just tried your steps, and got 126372 days.  Plugging that back into `date -d '126372 days'` gets me back to 2362-02-25.  If you get something different, you should include it in the question instead of making us guess.

Comment: I get 126373 which seems correct as well. What exactly is not working with what you are doing? Perhaps you have a 32 bit int, and my cygwin (which outputs "CYGWIN_NT-6.1 BTIS1000039378 2.3.1(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-14 12:44 **x86_64** Cygwin" for `uname -a`) has 64 bits?

Comment: It's funny though that on my 64 bit cygwin the maximum date for a correct computation seems roughly 2^31 years away, so it's not the seconds but the years, and it's 32 bit ints.

Comment: @TobySpeight date: invalid date `02/25/2362'
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider  : Output for uname -a (omitting the server name) 2.6.9-42.0.8.ELsmp #1 SMP Tue Jan 23 13:01:26 EST 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider . I think, I am running 32 bit machine. Output for `file /sbin/init` is "_/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped_" and output for `uname -m` is _i686_

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal Yeah, that's probably the issue.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I get _date: invalid date 02/25/2362_ for `date -d 02/25/2362`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in **number of days**

```
 $(( ($(date --date="30001020" +%s) - $(date --date="19701020" +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
```

This will give the difference between dates 3000-Oct-20 and 1970-Oct-20 
I believe date conversion **%s** isn't necessary but this what I tested .

Comment: This is a very naive solution and quite inaccurate, because it ignores [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: @ceving, it's pretty difficult to account for all leap seconds between now and February 2362, given that we don't know even next year's leap seconds...

Comment: Isn't this roughly equivalent to what the OP is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the [Julian day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) of both dates. It is explained [here](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/05/17/how-to-convert-date-to-julian-day-number-using-shell-script/), how to do it. After that you can subtract the two values.

Answer (score 0):

From the information added in comments, it seems that you are using a version of `date` which can't handle such distant dates.  By examining the error output for `date -d 02/25/2362`, we see

```
date: invalid date 02/25/2362
```

It may be possible to upgrade the `date` executable, but it may be that no (existing) date implementation for 32-bit Linux has sufficient range, leaving you to change OS, or to write the necessary code for an existing `date`.

For information, I can confirm that the implementation of date I'm using (64-bit Linux x86-64 ELF, `date (GNU coreutils) 8.21`) copes happily with dates twenty billion years either side of the present.

As an aside, it's probably worth arranging for your script to exit early if the `date` command fails, rather than allowing it to propogate bad inputs to the rest of your calculation.  The simple way to do this is to pass the `-e` option to your shell (assuming a Bourne-like shell, such as Bash or Dash).  You can do this by adding it to the `#!` line, or by writing `set -e` at the beginning of the program.